# Posting UTF-8 via Requests/GraphQL to Shopify shows no UTF-8

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm pushing data via the GraphQL API to Shopify (as metafields). I don't use a library like Graphene, just the `requests` library.

My post request shows with `response.headers`the encoding as UTF-8:

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 28 Jul 2020 14:33:52 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', ...
```

My payload includes Umlauts:

```
{
"query": "mutation($input: ProductInput!) { productUpdate(input: $input) { product { metafields(first: 100) { edges { node { id namespace key value } } } } }} ",
"variables": {
    "input": {
        "id": "gid://shopify/Product/5450527015065",
        "metafields": [
            {
                "namespace": "product-details",
                "key": "Kurzbeschreibung",
                "value": "Armband aus Leder mit grün glänzender Rüsche",
                "valueType": "STRING"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't understand, why I am not receiving the content on Shopify in Unicode
[image: quests]

This is how I read the data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dictionary = df.to_dict('index')
print(dictionary)
```

Returns:

```
0: {'Handle': 'd1', 'metafields.product-details.Kurzbeschreibung': 'Armband aus Leder mit grün glänzender Rüsche', 'metafields.product-details.Style': 'Das ArmRock Armband ist das perfekte Finish für jedes Styling. Bei diesem Schmuck-Accessoire für Arm, Hals oder auch Fuß kommt das FederRock Label prägende feinste Hirschleder zum Einsatz, als Band mit feinen Rüschen in buntem Akzentleder geschmückt. Das ArmRock Band besticht durch sein raffiniertes Design und garantiert ein echter Hingucker. Jedes Modell wird individuell gefertigt und ist ein Unikat.'}, 1:
```

**EDIT:**
Narrowed the problem and created another issue here: [Python code generated by Insomnia GraphQL client reacts not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141535/python-code-generated-by-insomnia-graphql-client-reacts-not-as-expected)

Comment: Is the data you're sending actually UTF-8 encoded…!?

Comment: The data I am importing to Python is in a CSV. ```file -I "xxx.csv"```gives me ```xxx.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8```. There are no further encodings within my application, as Python deals with UTF-8 natively

Comment: `file` is just giving you a guess. How exactly are you reading that data and can you print it correctly to screen, putting any API calls aside for the moment?

Comment: updated my post, prints umlauts correctly

Comment: I narrowed down the issue and created another SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141535/python-code-generated-by-insomnia-graphql-client-reacts-not-as-expected

Comment: The link to other issue does not work.